# image taken from url does not show up is

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Well i am having a custom cell and this is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"ListTableCell";
    //this is the identifier of the custom cell
    ListsCell *cell = (ListsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSURL *url_left=[NSURL URLWithString:[images_url objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)]];
    cell.Left.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url_left]];
    NSURL *url_right=[NSURL URLWithString:[images_url objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2+1)]];
    cell.Right.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url_right]];


    return cell;
}
```

Urls are fine because I print them out in NSLog and they are fine. Also if I place a static image from the properties I can see it, I just can see the image coming from the web.

The array image_url gets its url's by parsing a json array if this has nothing to do.

Also in my

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
... images_url filling with data.
    [self.myTable.reloadData];
}
```

I reload the data.

Why is that?

I also have these methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int i=[images_url count]/2;
    return i;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 81;
}
```

Do not waste time , in [images count]/2. This is because i have there lets say 10 urls, but since in my custom cell I have 2 imageviews per cell, I need 5 lines.

Comment: There are a couple problems I can see. First off, you call `[self.myTable.reloadData]`; I don't know how that's compiling, since you're not sending any message there. I think you want a space, rather than a period, before `reloadData`. Second, I don't think you get `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` for the method `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` - you're not using an NSURLConnection with a delegate, so that never gets called. Finally, how long are you waiting? If you're doing this all on the main thread, you may need to wait quite a while before your images show up, depending on their sizes.

Comment: well no matter how much i will wait they will not show up. If i remover the reloadData then each cell has its default size. Woth the reload data size is adjusted, clickabe cells are only 5 but the only problem is that I cannot see the content. So what do you suggest for it? i think it is your second hypothesis. (in the connectionDidFinish i do fetch my json object but I have just removed the code)